# How to add String Array and Integer Array from XML into one Collection

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, collections

Hey Guys I wanna Create Something like this in Recycler View

[Example Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAofr.png)

I already has a class named `HomeStep`

```
data class HomeStep(
    val icon: Int,
    val circle: Int,
    val textName: String)
```

I already store icon (Green One) and circle as integer Array in `string.xml`

```
<integer-array name="icon_drawble">
    <item>@drawable/icon_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/icon_4</item>
</integer-array>

<integer-array name="circle_drawble">
    <item>@drawable/circle_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/circle_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/circle_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/circle_4</item>
</integer-array>
```

I have already stored icon and circle as string Array in `string.xml` also

```
<string-array name="list_step">
    <item>@string/step_1_text</item>
    <item>@string/step_2_text</item>
    <item>@string/step_3_text</item>
    <item>@string/step_4_text</item>
</string-array>
```

Is it possible to add my Integer-array and string-array in Collection ?

```
val listHomeStep = ArrayList<HomeStep>()
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    val adapter = HomeStepAdapter()

    var icon: Int
    var circle: Int
    var textName: String

    var i = 0
    while (i < listHomeStep.size) {
        icon = resources.getIntArray(R.array.icon_drawble)[i]
        circle = resources.getIntArray(R.array.circle_drawable)[i]
        textName = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_step)[i]
        i++
    }

    listHomeStep.addAll(icon, circle, textName)
    adapter.setDataList(listHomeStep)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can add Integer-array or String-array to Collection

In your case, you should insert the `HomeStep` one by one, like this

```
    val listHomeStep = ArrayList<HomeStep>()
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    val adapter = HomeStepAdapter()

    var icon: Int
    var circle: Int
    var textName: String

    var i = 0
    while (i < listHomeStep.size) {
        icon = resources.getIntArray(R.array.icon_drawble)[i]
        circle = resources.getIntArray(R.array.circle_drawable)[i]
        textName = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_step)[i]
        val homeStep = HomeStep(icon, circle, textName)
        listHomeStep.add(homeStep)
        i++
    }

    adapter.setDataList(listHomeStep)
```